# How to covert std::string to NSString?Look at the last picture

Tags: ios, objective-c++

How to covert std::string to NSString? ,why the result is garbled?I use lldb command `po` ,look at the console ，the red arrow,the `_data` display correct string？Why?

```
 std::string resultString = getResult();
 NSString *str= [NSString stringWithCString:resultString.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but the str is  garbled,like [image]

[image]

[image: why str's value = nil]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was in `resultString`?

Comment: your code is fine unless `resultString` does not store UTF8 encoded string. and you can just do `@(resultString.c_str())`

Comment: The code is fine. If you split out the c_str() call to its own `const char* variable` and look at its result in the debugger, what does it say? From what I see in the NSString, there is a ASCII 01 character in there, which is not invalid, but unusual for text. Is your original string correct? Did you maybe get that `std::string` from some binary data and forget to zero-terminate it or forget to specify its length when creating it?

Comment: in the third picture,why the str's value is nil.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `.c_str()` may do extra copying. A more direct way would be `[NSString stringWithBytes:resultString.data() length:resultString.length() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be here issue is with string encoding. I have done little test on this input string and found some result on that.

Here I have use complex string `"\x18\xa4\tp\x01"` which you shown in your log. From the result I conclude that `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding string is not working with above string.

Here is code:

```
+ (void) stringTest {

    std::string *resultString = new std::string("\x18\xa4\tp\x01");

    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithCString:resultString->c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *str2= [NSString stringWithCString:resultString->c_str() encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *str3= [NSString stringWithCString:resultString->c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"str :%@",str);
    NSLog(@"str2 :%@",str2);
    NSLog(@"str3 :%@",str3);
}
```

And a reference image for log:

[image]

Here you can see that `NSUTF8StringEncoding` returns `nil` string and other encoding gives a result. I'm not sure which encoding scheme is valid for your string. If we know that encoding scheme for `resultString` string then we can get more accurate result here.

Comment: The function **getResult()** should return a character string,but the result is "\x18\xa4\tp\x01",I have no idea about this.Thank you.

Comment: @jackbolo: Have a try above solution with `getResult()`. I have no idea what it will, but at least w'll know about output.

Comment: Can you explain the contents of the red rectangle in the last picture. The `resultString` = `<s> 给 <unk> <_Contact_> 吴工 </_Contact_> <unk> 打 个 电 话 </s> \n -15.10 `,waht the meaning of the `_data` array?

Comment: Here variable `s` is an array of character. So each characters are stored as an element of an array is variable `s[]`. Here `_data` is manage by system to represent array. It is a naming convention used by system.

Comment: What the relationship betweent `_data` and `resultString`,or there is no relationship between `_data` and `resultString`.

Comment: It is good to be curious but look it is an internal representation of `std::string` to manage data. And also I haven't explore that much in details.

Comment: Can you explain the last picture?

Comment: I have explain that it is an internal representation to manage characters in `std::string`. And I haven't explore that much in details. You should search for some books or blogs that may help you to understand the "How internal representation of `std::string` is managed?".